# Select on Join error could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, outer-join

I'm implementing this function:

```
DECLARE @Type AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @Type='Student'
SELECT Users.NTID, @Type
    FROM Users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses
        ON Users.NTID=Courses.Faculty

        GROUP BY Users.NTID

        IF (Users.NTID=Courses.Faculty) 
        BEGIN
         SET @Type='Faculty'
        END
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Users.NTID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Courses.Faculty" could not be bound.
```

If I don't add this, it displays all the rows as Students

```
IF (Users.NTID=Courses.Faculty) 
            BEGIN
             SET @Type='Faculty'
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from trying to use values from the query in code outside the query. The `if` statement is not part of the query.

What I believe that you want is something like this, the gets users where there is a matching record in the Courses table, and users where there is no matching record:

```
select
  Users.NTID, 'Student'
from
  Users
  left join Courses on Users.NTID = Courses.Faculty
where
  Courses.Faculty is null

union all

select
  Users.NTID, 'Faculty'
from
  Users
  inner join Courses on Users.NTID = Courses.Faculty
group by
  Users.NTID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Both you are getting this error because your if statement is out of the scope for the Users.NTID and Courses.Faculty fields.

You can try this query if you want to mark the records on Users table as Students/Faculty. It simply gets your if statement inside the select.

> SELECT DISTINCT Users.NTID, CASE WHEN Courses.Faculty IS NULL THEN 'Faculty' ELSE 'Student' END AS PersonType
>   FROM Users
>       LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses ON Users.NTID=Courses.Faculty